# Why function enter on my textarea didn't working

Tags: php, textarea, contact-form

I create simple contact form with textarea as a message:

```
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
```

But when I create example :

```
test1
test2
'test'
```

with enter every word and its become `test1test2'test'`
I think any mistake when user click enter, and the email i receive with no 'enter'

I use php FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING in my textarea post.

```
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

And the last execute code to my email:

```
function email($to, $email, $name, $subject, $body){
    $header = array();
    $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $header[] = "From: $email";
    $header[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
    $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br) function....

```
 $message = nl2br(filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nl2br to transform new lines to `<br />`

```
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
```